# Laravel - How to show edit and delete button on 1 row from two forms?

Tags: html, laravel, class, layout

I have two forms with at the bottom respectively a button to update and to delete the data. I want to place the buttons on 1 line.

The problem is when I am using "div class row" to place the button on the same row and leave them open between the two forms (see code)
my data is deleted when I press de update button. If I close the "div class row" then naturally the buttons are working perfectly but they are now on different rows.

How can I fix this? Thanks for the help.

```
## Leave the class open ==> Update      Delete

        <form method="POST" action="/tasks/{{ $event->id }}" >
            @csrf
            @method('PATCH')

            ...

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-4 offset-1">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
        </form>
        <form action="/tasks/{{$task->id}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
                <div class="col-4 offset-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

## Leave the class open ==> Update
                                         Delete

        <form method="POST" action="/tasks/{{ $event->id }}" >
            @csrf
            @method('PATCH')

            ...

            <div class="col-4 offset-1">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
        </form>

        <form action="/tasks/{{$task->id}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
                <div class="col-4 offset-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a tricky one. Have you considered using JavaScript for the delete button?

Change the button type to button and add the `onclick` attribute to the button and submit the delete form on click.

```
    <form method="POST" action="/tasks/{{ $event->id }}" >
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')

        ...

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-4 offset-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Update</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 offset-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" 
                onclick="event.preventDefault(); 
                        document.getElementById('delete-task-form').submit();"
                ">Delete</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
    <form action="/tasks/{{$task->id}}" id="delete-task-form" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
    </form>
```

Comment: Or maybe ```<button form="delete-task-form">```

Comment: @Robbin Benard -- Brilliant! How did I not know this existed?!

Comment: Just commenting to thank Robbin for this code. Helped me out in a neat way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with display flex and align child accordingly to what you wish to achieve. 
Here's some lecture:
https://css-tricks.com/quick-whats-the-difference-between-flexbox-and-grid/

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert all the forms inside the div. So instead of wrapping them with form tag you want to wrap them with div, and put the form inside the div. That way you can arrange the button with col-md class more easily.

```
<div class="col-4 offset-6">
       <form action="/tasks/{{$task->id}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not help. Because then I need to still leave the div for the row open in order to get them on 1 line and then I still got the problem that my edit button operates as a delete button. And I can't wrap the forms inside the tag because I have my input fields for my edit button who belong to this form for editing.